# Can someone explain the relationship between normal color vs vector angle?

Tags: 3d-view, normals

So here's my problem:

what are you seeing here is a UV Sphere in 3D view with Normal pass (displaying object space normals)
[image]

[image]

Can someone explain how are we supposed to know the normal angle (surface prependicular) in the case B?

There's this octant in a geometry where all R,G,B values are 0 and I'm trying to wrap my head around why that's the case

Comment: I think we're missing some information we need to answer your question. Are you using object space normals? The angle you're trying to determine is between what two vectors or are you talking about angles in polar coordinates?

Comment: I updated the qustion with more info! And I'm talking purely visual, RGB is supposed to represent XYZ normal, but theres a big area where all RGB values are zero (the black part). Why is that the case?